# laravel model event static call issue

Tags: events, laravel, model, static

Why my static method don´t work with a varible class?

```
    /**
 * Events
 */
public static function boot() {

    parent::boot();

    $class = get_called_class(); // The value os $class is: Product ( string)

    // This work  
    Product::creating(function($model) {
                return $model->validate();
            });

    // Don´t work, the closure never called!
    $class::creating(function($model) {
                return $model->validate();
            });

    $class::updating(function($model) {
                return $model->validate(true);
            });
}
```

Incredible, this work to:

```
   $class = "Product"; //get_called_class();
```

**Solution ( Not elegant , but ... )**

On my Product model i put this, to share class name with Base model.

```
 public static function boot() {
    parent::$cls = "Product"; 
    parent::boot();        
 }
```

but updating does not work yet!

Answer (score 0):

Actually (since PHP 5.3) it should work to do:

```
$class = 'Product';
$class::creating(function($model){
    return $model->validate();
});
```

But why not just use [`static::`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#104823) to access the current class? This way you don't need `get_called_class`:

```
static::creating(function($model){
    return $model->validate();
});
```

There's also [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) if everything else fails...

Comment: i use get_called_class  to create a BaseModel ( Generic ) to be extended by another models. The static::creating have the same effect!

Comment: The fact that it works if you define `"Product"` in the child model means that `get_called_class()` does not return `"Product"`

Comment: Yes, i put some logs to check that , i don´t no why , but this is true log show User model. Probably is a noob issue, XD!